# Vivoi coin fork, no debug.log

Tags: fork, bitcoin

So, a few days ago I forked Vivo coin for fun.
I edited the name to something random (somecoin), I deleted the checkpoints, the merkle root, the `genesis` hash.
I compile with `./autogen.sh` then I do the `./configure` then `make`.
After that i get the `daemon`, the `-qt` file and the `-cli` file.
I run the daemon and get the error:

> somecoind: chainparams.cpp:127: CMainParams::CMainParams():
>   Assertion 'consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x")' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

So I close the daemon and look for the `debug.log` file to get the merkle root, the genesis hash and nNonce.
But the `.somecoin` folder is empty. I do the `ls -a` and there are no hidden files in the folder.

Comment: Vivo coin. sorry typo.

Answer (score -1):

You're saying you broke it, and now it aborts. Remedy is pretty simple: reset the repo back to how you originally found it, and make a small enough set of changes that it no longer aborts. You will learn important package details along the way.

Comment: No, i deleted the merkle root and the genesis hash. I run the daemon, and it crashes (as it is supposed to do). Then i should find a folder with a debug.log file in it. On that debug.log file I should find the merke root hash and genesis hash. But there is no debug.log.

Comment: When launching the daemon under gdb, you may find commands like this useful: `break chainparams.cpp:127`